# Ramsey number $R(n,n) > (n-1)^2$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, ramsey-theory

I got an home work assignment, prove that:

$R(n,n) > (n-1)^2$

Note that I saw on Wikipedia that for subgraph of $K_n$  with k vertices, $R(k,k) > 2^{k/2}$.

I tried to work with that, but still it doesn't really helps me.

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union of $n-1$ copies of $K_{n-1}$ is a graph with $(n-1)^2$ vertices which doesn't contain $K_n$ nor $n$ independent vertices. This proves $R(n,n) > (n-1)^2$ by definition of the Ramsey number.

Comment: @shukjin   How can I prove formally that new graph doesn't contain $K_n$ ?

Comment: @RoeyWaitsman Let's call the complete subgraphs $C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_{n-1}$. If the new graph contains $K_n$, the vertices of $K_n$ cannot be completely contained in one $C_i$. So there must be two vertices in $K_n$ that are not adjacent, a contradiction.

Comment: @shukjin thx mate that's clear now